# Split queryset or get multiple querysets by field instead of just ordering by field

Tags: python, django, models

I want to query a database in a way such that rather than just ordering by some field, I get a separate QuerySet (or dictionary, list, whatever) for each unique value of that field.  Hopefully the below example will help:

Suppose a model like

```
Class Person(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField()
   last_name = models.CharField
```

Calling Person.objects.all().order_by('last_name') gives me a single long QuerySet.  I want instead to have a separate list for each unique last_name.  So one list for every Person with last_name="Smith" and another list for every Person with last_name="Nguyen" etc.

Obviously I can't know ahead of time what last_names will be in the database, nor how many people will share a common last_name. Is there any fast, efficient, or automatic way to do this in django or do I just need to process the data myself after getting the one large queryset back?

Comment: `order_by` `last_name`, then iterate with `itertools.groupby` might also be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all the unique lastnames:

```
from django.db.models import Count
...
last_names = Person.objects.values('last_name').annotate(Count('last_name')) # This will return all the unique last_names
values = dict( ((last_name['last_name'], Person.objects.all().filter(last_name = last_name['last_name'])) for last_name in last_names if last_name['last_name__count']) )
# This will create a dictionary where the keys are all the unique names and the values are querysect of all the values that have that lastname
```

Daniel-Roseman is right it is pretty inefficient so heres a tweak version ...

```
from collections import defaultdict
values = defaultdict(list)
_ = map(lambda person: values[person.last_name].append(person), Person.objects.all())
```

note that `_ = ...` is so we don't print all the `None` on the terminal ;)

Answer (score 13):

samy's code is correct, but pretty inefficient: you do n+1 queries (where n is the number of unique last names). Since you're going to be getting all the objects in the table anyway, you might as well do it in one go. Use this instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
person_dict = defaultdict(list)
persons = Person.objects.all()
for person in persons:
    person_dict[person.last_name].append(person)
```

Comment: This still causes multiple queries + the all query. Am I missing something on why this is happening?

Answer (score 9):

Look at the [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) tag.

```
{% regroup persons by last_name as surname_list %}

<ul>
{% for last_name in surname_list %}
    <li>{{ last_name.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for person in last_name.list %}
          <li>{{ person.last_name }}, {{ person.first_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

(this code is untested, please read the docs and fix any problem yourself)

Comment: Thank you!  This is really helpful.  I tried to moderate up but I lack the reputation score to do so currently, I'll come back to it after I've raised my reputation.  I'm accepting the below answer since it does the work in the view rather than template.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you think doing the grouping at the view has any advantage over doing it at the template? Seems like doing the grouping at the template would lead to cleaner code at the view and better performance (remember querysets are lazy in django).