# Django: Break query result into multiple lists of common elements

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

**EDIT**: Added all relevant models. Added clarification.

I have to query a table called **Data**, but instead of having just 1 list returned, possibly have several lists returned from a query. Otherwise take the queryset result and break it into an array of objects with common **SensorParameter** fields.

I have model **Data**:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    sensor_param = models.ForeignKey(SensorParameter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

And model **SensorParameter** has links to parameters (temperature, vibration, etc) and a sensor instance (serial number, etc):

```
class SensorParameter(models.Model):
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor)
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(Parameter)
```

And model **Parameter** (a container for different types of parameters the different sensors can possibly measure):

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    parameter_name          = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parameter_unit          = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

And finally a **Sensor** model that ties all others together:

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=True)
    serial_number   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sensor_type     = models.ForeignKey(SensorType)
```

I can query the **Data** table for a certain time range period from a certain **Sensor** by doing a double backwards lookup and ordering the resulting query the way I'd like to have my lists broken down, first by **sensor_parameter**, then by **time**:

```
sensor = Sensor.objects.get(serial_number=request["data_source"])
range_period = [request['start'], request['end']]
# This is the queryset I have now, though it's not set in stone
data_query = Data.objects.filter(sensor_parameter__sensor=sensor, time__range=range_period).order_by('sensor_parameter', 'time')
```

This results in a list of all data points, for the time period requested, for the sensor requested, in **one big list**.

How can I then break down the resulting list into several lists (or an array) of objects with common **SensorParameter** fields?

Example from:

```
queryset_overall_result =
[
    {data_point_1: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: temp, value: 188, time: 00:01}
    {data_point_2: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: vibration, value: 5, time: 00:01}
    {data_point_3: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: temp, value: 185, time: 00:02}
    {data_point_4: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: vibration, value: 6, time: 00:02}
]
```

To:

```
list_temp =
[
    {data_point_1: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: temp, value: 188, time: 00:01}
    {data_point_3: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: temp, value: 185, time: 00:02}
]

list_vibration = 
[
    {data_point_2: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: vibration, value: 5, time: 00:01}
    {data_point_4: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: vibration, value: 6, time: 00:02}
]
```

Is there a better way to query the Data table to give me **several** lists arranged by time while filtered to another table? (SensorParameter)

Or having the overall queryset result, use python to break it down into multiple lists of common object elements? An array would be ideal, but not sure how to accomplish this.

Ideal scenario:

```
array = 
[
    [
        {data_point_1: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: temp, value: 188, time: 00:01}
        {data_point_3: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: temp, value: 185, time: 00:02}
    ]
,
   [
        {data_point_2: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: vibration, value: 5, time: 00:01}
        {data_point_4: sensor: X, sensor_parameter: vibration, value: 6, time: 00:02}
    ]
]
```

Constraints: I don't know how many or which **SensorParameters** a **Sensor** can measure, this can be anywhere from 4 to 45ish depending on the **Sensor_sensor_type**. I need to try to keep queries to a minimum as this query can possibly return a ton of data and could possibly happen many times in quick succession. The less DB hits the better.

Comment: If you provide the exact queryset (and the code for all models involved) used to get the `queryset_overall_result` list, it should be possible to find a fast and concise solution rather than looping through lists in Python.

Comment: The entire queryset is: `data_query = Data.objects.filter(sensor_parameter__sensor=sensor, time__range=range_period).order_by('sensor_parameter', 'time')`

I'll add code for the other model I didn't include in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the sensors and parameters and sensor_parameters are making my head spin, but I'll give it a try. If you want to group your results by `SensorParameter`, the default approach is to query that model:

```
qs = (SensorParameter.objects
    .filter(sensor=sensor, data__time__range=range_period)
    .select_related('sensor', 'parameter')
    .distinct()
    .order_by('sensor_parameter'))
```

Since you want to access the related `Data` objects ordered by time, you should issue an appropriate `prefetch_related` command:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
sorted_data_qs = (Data.objects
    .filter(time__range=range_period)
    .order_by('time'))
prefetch = Prefetch('data_set', queryset=sorted_data_qs)
qs = qs.prefetch_related(prefetch) #  using qs from above
```

With just two SQL queries, you now have all data grouped together by `SensorParameter` in individual `SensorParameter` objects. You can access the individual data rows as follows:

```
for rs in qs:
    for d in rs.data_set.all():
        print(rs.sensor.name, rs.parameter.name, d.value, d.time)
```

Of course there is some overhead in constructing objects; if you don't need them and only need rows of data, you could take another route:

Get a list of all the `SensorParameter`s that satisfy your filter, and then run individual queries for all of them, getting back dictionaries that you can put into a list as you originally envisioned:

```
sensor_params = (SensorParameter.objects
    .filter(sensor=sensor, data__time__range=range_period)
    .value_list('id', flat=True))

result_list = []
for sp in sensor_params:
    param_results = list(
        Data.objects
        .filter(sensor_parameter=sp, time__range=range_period)
        .order_by('time')
        .values(
            'sensor_parameter__sensor__name',
            'sensor_parameter__parameter__name',
            'value',
            'time'
        )
    )
    result_list.append(param_results)
```

This results in more queries (sensor count plus 1), but this doesn't mean it is necessarily slower than the first approach (it might even be quicker). Here again, the grouping is done in the database rather than in Python.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A database level operation with a minimum amount of queries that would break down the resulting query into several lists separated by common parameter_name. This answer also taught me a few things about querying the database I didn't know. Thank you very much for your thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and combine them into a list

```py
sensors = Sensor.objects.all()

array = []

for sensor in sensors:
    list_param = [d for d in data_query if d['sensor_parameter'] == sensor]
    array.append(list_param)
```

Comment: That works if I know what parameters I am looking for, but temp and vibration are just 2 out of 75ish options. I used those 2 as examples, but the list of parameters can be long or short, depending on what type of sensor data I am querying so I can't just write a query per each type of parameter.

Comment: I could query all the parameter types a sensor can have beforehand if that works, though I was looking to keep databasy queries to a minimum, so preferably a pure python way would be better, to split the one query result into several lists.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388296/split-queryset-or-get-multiple-querysets-by-field-instead-of-just-ordering-by-fi

Comment: Something like: `array = [d for d in data_query for each data_query.sensor_parameter]` (not actual Python, but a rough explanation of what I would need)

Comment: Yeah exactly. Check out my updated answer or use the defaultdict answer above if you could use a dict instead